# Store MySQL data in text file, create new file automatically if the number of rows exceeds 100

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing my database output in a .txt file. I am not having any problems, but I just want to store 100 rows of MySQL data in one .txt file and the rest in other text files with 100 rows in each file.

Here is my code which is generating all data in only one text file.

```
<?php 
  $File = "yourfile.txt"; 

  $Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
  $res = mysql_query("SELECT * from tableA");

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $oumu .= ''.$row4['title'].'';
  }

  $Data = $oumu; 
  fwrite($Handle, $Data); 
  print "Data Added"; 
  fclose($Handle); 
?>
```

It puts all data in one text file but I want to store only 100 rows in one text file and I want to automatically create the next file so that it can store 100 rows in each text file.

Comment: how many rows are in that table in total?

Comment: @gordon 65000 rows and sorry it will be mysql

Comment: @user1515503 I cleaned up your question a bit to make it a little clearer. Feel free to roll back if you're not happy with the edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php 
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * from tableA");
$rows = 0;
$oumu = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
$oumu[floor($rows)] .= ''.$row['title']."\r\n";
$rows += 0.01;
}
foreach ($oumu as $k => $v) {
$File = "yourfile" . ($k + 1)  . ".txt"; 
$Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
fwrite($Handle, $v); 
fclose($Handle); 
}
print "Data Added"; 
?>
```

Comment: OK, try it now. Make sure you connect to MySQL and select the database first.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;

while ($row = sql_fetch_array($res)) {

if($i == 100)
    break;

$oumu .= ''.$row4['title'].'';
$i++;
```

}

Also what is the "sql"? Did you mean "mysql_..."?

Comment: yes i mean mysql but in your case how it will create new files .i tried it is not even storing 100 rows there is no diference